# Like gate mechanism with Asp.Net MVC Facebook

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying out the ASP.Net MVC 4 Facebook template and "framework" and I'm finding it hard to get any help on the Internet, except from the "Birthday app" sample.

I'm building a simple Facebook application with a "like gate", meaning people should be able to access the app only if they have "liked" a certain page.

My idea is to check in the controller wether the user has "liked" the fan page and if he has not, redirect him to the "LikeFirst" view.

Here's the controller, straight from the template:

```
   [FacebookAuthorize("email", "user_photos")]
   public async Task<ActionResult> Index(FacebookContext context)
   {
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
          var user = await context.Client.GetCurrentUserAsync<MyAppUser>();

          if(//how check the user has liked the fan page)
          {
             return View(user);
          }
          else
          {
             return View("LikeFirst");
          }
       }

       return View("Error");
   }
```

From what I got in the sample, the Framework actually uses the "MyAppUser" object to construct the Facebook query.

This is the type used in the sample app.

```
public class MyAppUser
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("picture")] // This renames the property to picture.
    [FacebookFieldModifier("type(large)")] // This sets the picture size to large.
    public FacebookConnection<FacebookPicture> ProfilePicture { get; set; }

    [FacebookFieldModifier("limit(8)")] // This sets the size of the friend list to 8, remove it to get all friends.
    public FacebookGroupConnection<MyAppUserFriendSimple> Friends { get; set; }

    [FacebookFieldModifier("limit(16)")] // This sets the size of the photo list to 16, remove it to get all photos.
    public FacebookGroupConnection<FacebookPhoto> Photos { get; set; }
}
```

From the Facebook documentation, I should be able to check that simply through doing an HTTP GET to /PROFILE_ID/likes/PAGE_ID, but how should I do that using the ASP.Net MVC Facebook framework? Is there something I can change in the MyAppUser class? Is it something completely different?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So had this challenge just this morning - had to tinker with it a bit to figure it out. Here's what you do

Create a "Likes" property on your user type

```
public class MyAppUser
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public FacebookGroupConnection<FacebookLike> Likes { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Of course that means that you have to create a FacebookLike type

```
public class FacebookLike
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Add the following permission string to your FacebookAuthorizeAttribute

```
    [FacebookAuthorize("email", "user_photos", "user_likes")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(FacebookContext context)
    {
        ...
    }
```

and finally to find out of the user likes your page, you find your page Id and put the following code in the relevant controller method in which you want to perform the check -

```
            if (user.Likes.Data.FirstOrDefault(like => like.Id == "<your_fb_pageid>") == null)
            {
                return View("LikeUs");
            }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That's what I also tested, but I don't like that it gets all the pages the user likes just to verify that he likes one specific page.

In the API there definitively is a way to check that the user likes one page, but I have no clue how to call it using the Facebook MVC  template.

Answer (score 1):

Based on answer from Cordell Lawrence, actually if you want to only check if a user liked a page, a FacebookFieldModifier could be added

```
public class MyAppUser
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [FacebookFieldModifier("id({PAGE_ID})")]
    public FacebookGroupConnection<FacebookLike> Likes { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

FacebookLike class

```
public class FacebookLike
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Get permission from user

```
[FacebookAuthorize("email", "user_photos", "user_likes")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(FacebookContext context)
{
    ...
}
```

The most important thing is the FacebookFieldModifier.
If the user didn't like the page, the returned list from Facebook will be empty

I havent tried to compile the above codes, hope this help

Comment: hi, i have an issue using facebook like button, can you answer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29277265/absolute-url-for-facebook-like-button-in-asp-mvc) question